# How to send a base64 image in postman

Tags: postman

Need to make a request to a api with a image encoded in base64, the request is a put, and i was trying making in the body section using the raw format and adding i.e. this json:

```
{
 "picture": {
    "name": "/Users/Cokeina/Desktop/imagenes/default_avatar.png",
    "content_type": "image/png",
    "file": "base64string"
 }
}
```

but seems like this isn't working, what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Did you try the documentation? https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests#request-body Seems like form-data or binary is the way to go.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could find online base64 image encoder. They encode an image to a string.

The example of raw body in JSON format in the POSTMAN:

```
"profile": {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Dow",
    "photo": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABAQMAAAAl21bKAAAAA1BMVEUAAACnej3aAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAApJREFUCNdjYAAAAAIAAeIhvDMAAAAASUVORK5CYII="
}
```

I think, that "name" and "content_type" is obvious in your JSON.

Comment: what if I want to send an image in "form-data" body rather in "raw body"

Comment: @Imran_Developer You can choose the 'File' type of the key

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it:

```
// JSON body in Postman

{
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "photo": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABJgAAASsCAYAAADDvzILAAAZy3pUWHRSYXcgcHJvZmlsZSB0eXBlIGV4aWYAAHja7ZpZkhw5kkT/cYo5AvblOIZNpG8wx5+niCSHZBWlq7v6Z0SGyczIjMUdDlPTBXB3/vsf1/0X/2rx2eXSeh21ev7lkUc0fun+88/ez+Dz+/n+jf7+0t8/Pe9sfb0QeSrxmD4v9Pp5DN+e//rAt8dg/FZ+OFBfXy/Mn18Yn8P72H85..."
}
```

Then on the server, I store the image like so:

```
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));    // To allow for larger payloads

app.post("/selfie", (req, res) => {
 console.log('req.body:', req.body);
 var base64Data = req.body.photo.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
 
 require("fs").writeFile("out.png", base64Data, 'base64', function (err) {
   console.log(err);
 });
 
 res.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
let template = `
<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,{{img}}'/>
`;

pm.visualizer.set(template, { 
    img: pm.response.json()
});
```

[image: Postman response]

while the response is the base64 string