# Can't upload image and get expecteds behavior in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I've tried all possible options on this over the last two days and nothing seems to work. Please bear with me this will be a little long.

This is my UserProfile model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/user/', blank=True, null=True)
```

This is the Serializer,

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    thumbnail = serializers.ImageField(max_length=256, use_url=True, allow_empty_file=False)

    class Meta:
        model = models.UserProfile
        fields = ('status', 'thumbnail',)
```

Now when I try to upload this image using POSTMAN, this the output that I get,

```
{
    "thumbnail": [
        "No file was submitted."
    ]
}
```

Reading some SO posts I tried replacing the default serializer.ImageField to the this,

```
class Base64ImageField(serializers.ImageField):
    """
    A Django REST framework field for handling image-uploads through raw post data.
    It uses base64 for encoding and decoding the contents of the file.

    Heavily based on
    https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/1268

    Updated for Django REST framework 3.
    """

    def to_internal_value(self, data):

        # Check if this is a base64 string
        if isinstance(data, six.string_types):
            # Check if the base64 string is in the "data:" format
            if 'data:' in data and ';base64,' in data:
                # Break out the header from the base64 content
                header, data = data.split(';base64,')

            # Try to decode the file. Return validation error if it fails.
            try:
                decoded_file = base64.b64decode(data)
            except TypeError:
                self.fail('invalid_image')

            # Generate file name:
            file_name = str(uuid.uuid4())[:12]  # 12 characters are more than enough.
            # Get the file name extension:
            file_extension = self.get_file_extension(file_name, decoded_file)

            complete_file_name = "%s.%s" % (file_name, file_extension,)
            data = ContentFile(decoded_file, name=complete_file_name)

        return super(Base64ImageField, self).to_internal_value(data)

    def get_file_extension(self, file_name, decoded_file):
        import imghdr

        extension = imghdr.what(file_name, decoded_file)
        extension = "jpg" if extension == "jpeg" else extension

        return extension
```

Nothing changes and I continue to get the exact same behaviour. The output that I'm expecting is something like this.

```
{
  "status":"something",
  "thumbnail":"file/path"
}
```

This is how I'm uploading an image using POSTMAN.

[image]

Can someone please help me with this, I've pretty much tried out every option on SO to no avail.

Comment: show you post data, please.

Comment: @BearBrown there's no post data, I'm just using POSTMAN to upload an image. I'll edit the question with a screenshot.

Comment: @BearBrown am I supposed to hardcode the path to the image and send it in the POST body and not do any file upload at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should send base64 encoded image data (not file upload) via postman (in case, you are using Base64ImageField)

You can refer this also: [Error uploading image using postman in django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50545408/error-uploading-image-using-postman-in-django-rest-framework/50545588#50545588)

[How to send a base64 image in postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977408/how-to-send-a-base64-image-in-postman)

Process of getting encoded image

1. Use [Image encoder](http://base64-image.de) for image encoding. After image upload, you will have an option of copy image.
2. Copy the data and paste it in and .txt file
3. You will get an string with prefix 'data:image/png;base64,'
4. Remove that prefix from string and paste the whole string in POSTMAN

Comment: It's not a good idea to put the big code if you can put a small link of that code.

Comment: @MelissaStewart What issue you are facing in old answer, it is supposed to work as i am using this in my project.

Comment: @SHIVAMJINDAL when you say not upload an image via postman but rather send base64 image data can you explain the process in detail in postman context because that's show I still have to test. I expect an image to be uploaded to the media directory and the response displaying it's path. How do I do that?

Comment: As I can see in image you are uploading image file via postman but in my answer, I have suggested to send base64 encoded image data via postman. I have also added a link to help you in sending base64 data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171931/discussion-between-melissa-stewart-and-shivam-jindal).

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to use multipart/form-data to upload the image along with your other json data, something like this:

```
# create a custom image field with additional constraints e.g. size of the image
class ConstrainedImageField(ImageField):
    MAX_SIZE = 2000000  # in Bytes
    default_error_messages = {
        'image_size': _('The size of the image is {image_size} KB. The maximum size allowed is: {max_size} KB.'),
    }

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        super(ConstrainedImageField, self).to_internal_value(data=data)
        file_size = data.size
        if file_size > self.MAX_SIZE:
            max_size_kb = self.MAX_SIZE/1000
            file_size_kb = file_size/1000
            self.fail('image_size', max_size=max_size_kb, image_size=file_size_kb)



class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    thumbnail = serializers.ConstrainedImageField(max_length=256, use_url=True, allow_empty_file=False)

    class Meta:
        model = models.UserProfile
        fields = ('status', 'thumbnail',)

    def validate(self, data):
        # ..
        # ..

        # get the image data from request.FILES:
        self.context["thumbnail"] = self.context['request'].FILES.get("thumbnail")
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # set the thumbnail field:
        validated_data['thumbnail'] = self.context.get("thumbnail")
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return user_profile
```